# Enterprise Architect - SVN Version Control

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am using Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems. I have a 1 model project and several packages are version controlled. I am using SVN to check in these model/packages.

I would like to understand what would be the best way to add a package tree to existing package tree which is already version controlled?

For Example, I have following structure which is already version controlled -

```
Model
 -- Package 1
      -- Package 2
        -- Package 3
```

Now I would like to add another set of packages

```
Model
 -- Package 1
       -- Package 2
           -- Package 3
       -- Package A
           -- Package B
                -- Package C
```

The package A (& B and C) is imported from another project, and it already exists. All I want to do is create these new tree under Version Control setup, so that I can check in new tree under Package 1. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these steps:

- Check out `Package 1` (allows addition of new packages/elements).
- Import `Package A` (and its children) into `Package 1`.
- Make `Package A` version controlled (since you want it to be on its own).
- Check in `Package 1`.